# How to correctly establish the type argument to CancellationToken in Net Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, clean-architecture, onion-architecture

I'm developing a clean Architecture's services on Net Core. However when I refactor the methods, it return me the error cs0411. more specifically in the `'GetSubjectById'` method when the Cancellation Token is usage and it didnt provide the type argument.

`IRepository.cs` #this is the repository interfaces that contain controller's method

```
public interface IRepository
    {
        Task<Subject> GetSubjectById(int id, CancellationToken CancellationToken);           
    }
```

`MethodRepository.cs` #this is the methods for the below Interface

```
  public class SubjectRepository : ISubjectRepository
    {
        private readonly dbContext _context;
        private ISubjectRepository _subject;

        
         public ISubjectRepository Subject {
            get {
                if(_subject == null)
                {
                    _subject = new SubjectRepository(_context);
                }
                return _subject;
            }
         }
        public SubjectRepository(dbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
        public async Task<Subject> GetSubjectById(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            return  _context.Subjects.FirstOrDefault(o => o.StudentId == id, cancellationToken) #This code line cause the error cs0411;
            
        }
}
```

If anyone could bring me some, I'd be really grateful.

Comment: what is `_context.Subjects`? do you mean to use `FirstOrDefaultAsync`?

Comment: Thats the dbContext for subject model.

Comment: You have an async method that doesn't contain any await calls.

Comment: That implementation doesn't make sense in more than that aspect. Why the `Subject` property?

Comment: Obviously, because thats the model as it shown below. If you dont want to provide useful solutions, please hold yourself to denigrate people by their doubts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just because `FirstOrDefault` doesn't have `CancellationToken` parameter, but `FirstOrDefaultAsync` does. Try this

```
    public Task<Subject> GetSubjectById(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return  _context.Subjects.FirstOrDefaultAsync(o => o.StudentId == id, cancellationToken)
        
    }
```

Comment: Either remove `async` or add `await`.